# Обновление БД используя SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

Добрый день! Уже много часов подряд не могу разобраться в чем ошибка: приложение написано на WPF, на форме присутствует `DataGrid`, который получает данные из БД MS SQL. Данные выводятся отлично, но нужно сделать, что бы при изменении значения в любой ячейке `DataGrid` сразу обновлялась информация в БД.

Компилируется отлично, но при изменении ячейки вылетает исключение -

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Для обновления требуется действительный
>   UpdateCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с измененными строками.

Что я не так делаю?

Код формы:

```
public partial class Administrator : Window
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    SqlDataAdapter sdaDoctor = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dtDoctor;
    SqlConnection cnDoctor;

    public Administrator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        /* Настройка подключения */
        bldr.DataSource = @"LUCIFER";
        bldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        bldr.AttachDBFilename = @"D:\Dropbox\Универ\2 семестр\Курсач\Hospital\Hospital\bin\Debug\Hospital.mdf";

        this.cnDoctor = new SqlConnection(bldr.ConnectionString);

        DoctorUpdateAdapted();

    }

    private void DoctorUpdateAdapted() // Создание команды на обновление
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "UPDATE Access" +
            "SET id = @id, type = @type" +
            "WHERE id = @id", this.cnDoctor);

        command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).SourceColumn = "id";
        command.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, "type");

        this.sdaDoctor.UpdateCommand = command;
    }

    private void GetDoctor(string querySQL) // Заполнение DataGrid данными
    {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, this.cnDoctor); 
                this.sdaDoctor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                this.dtDoctor = new DataTable("Doctor");
                sdaDoctor.Fill(dtDoctor);
                doctorGrid.ItemsSource = dtDoctor.DefaultView;
            }

            catch (SqlException error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка! " + error.Message);
            }
    }

    private void TabItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // После загруки DataGrid сразу его заполнить данными
    {
        string querySQL = "SELECT * FROM Access" + ";"; // SQL запрос
        GetDoctor(querySQL);
    }

    private void doctorGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) // После окончания редактирования ячейки обновить данные в БД
    {
        sdaDoctor.Update(dtDoctor);
    }
}
}
```

На всякий случай XAML код, может поможет:

```
<Window x:Class="Hospital.Forms.Administrator"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Администратор" Height="300" MinWidth="320">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Врачи" Loaded="TabItem_Loaded">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="160" MinWidth="110" Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <DataGrid IsReadOnly="False" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="doctorGrid" CellEditEnding="doctorGrid_CellEditEnding"></DataGrid>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button MaxWidth="150" MinWidth="100" Margin="5" Click="Doctor_Add_Click">Добавить врача</Button>
                    <Button MaxWidth="150" MinWidth="100" Margin="5">Найти врача</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Пациенты">Вторая вкладка</TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Пользователи">Пользователи</TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Обновление**

Все мои проблемы были в том, что я подключался к БД которая в папке bin/debug, а студия при каждой компиляции ее заменяет на копию из директории проекта. Я поэтому очень долго не мог понять, почему не обновляются данные, поэтому решил переписать рабочий код, а вышел не очень рабочий =) Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас SQL запрос составлен некорректно, Вы забыли пробелы:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "UPDATE Access" +
        "SET id = @id, type = @type" +
        "WHERE id = @id", this.cnDoctor);
```

Склеив строку получаем: `UPDATE AccessSET id = @id, type = @typeWHERE id = @id`

Поэтому код должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "UPDATE Access " +
            "SET id = @id, type = @type " +
            "WHERE id = @id", this.cnDoctor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Никто не знает, как сделать так, чтобы данные обновлялись?

Если база находится не в папке с проектом, а на другом компьютере, они соединены локально. Допустим, написанным приложением будут пользоваться несколько людей на разных компьютерах, а сам сервер с базой на другом, что бы при добавлении или изменении записей в проекте обновлялась и база данных.